# Issue with Typescript and Children - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children})

Tags: reactjs, typescript, children

I am currently getting an error and I just started using typescript. I haven't had an issue with React before on this issue. Basically I created a can component to check permissions before rendering a component. I pass in children to be rendered if they have permissions. However I'm getting I cannot pass children as an object which I'm not sure why this is happening. It also says I have Property 'children' is missing in type. Which I clearly have children in the file.

Here is the piece of code that is through the errors

```
{NAVIGATION_LIST.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Can
            checkAll={false}
            permissions={[item.permission]}
          >
            <IconButton
              aria-label={item.id}
              sx={{
                color: 'common.white',
                padding: (theme) => theme.spacing(1.5),
              }}
            >
              {item.icon}
            </IconButton>
          </Can>
        );
      })}
```

As you can see I have the child as

Here is my can component

```
// React
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

// Redux
import { RootState } from '../../redux/store';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

// Interfaces
interface CanProps {
  key?: string | number;
  checkAll?: boolean;
  permissions: string[];
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const Can = ({ checkAll = true, permissions, children }: CanProps) => {
  // Local State
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);

  // Redux State
  const reduxAuthenticationPermissions = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.authentication.permissions);

  // Lets
  let userHasValidPermissions = false;

  console.log('Check All: ', checkAll);
  console.log(permissions);
  console.log(reduxAuthenticationPermissions);
  console.log('Children: ', children);

  // Check if permissions passed match user permissions
  useMemo(() => {
    if (checkAll) {
      userHasValidPermissions = permissions.every((p) => reduxAuthenticationPermissions.includes(p));
    } else {
      userHasValidPermissions = permissions.some((p) => reduxAuthenticationPermissions.includes(p));
    }

    setIsAuthorized(userHasValidPermissions);
  }, [permissions, reduxAuthenticationPermissions, checkAll])

  return (
    <>
      {isAuthorized && (
        {children}
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Can;
```

In this component is checks if the user needs all or one permission, sets the isAuthorized attribute and then renders or doesn't render the children. However this never happens.

I have to be missing something easy its just Typescript seems a little different on this piece. I've looked through a few other posts about this but they were fairly easy to spot like passing an actual object to the component instead of the attribute needed or something like that.

Comment: You're accidentally creating an object. Change `{isAuthorized && ({children})}` to `{isAuthorized && children}`

Comment: @NicholasTower That worked, I knew it was something stupid. I had an linter that was auto correcting to that I have fixed it and its working properly now!